# How are brute force attacks hitting my WP website after renaming wp-admin folder?

Tags: wordpress

We maintain several wordpress websites which receive regular attempts at brute forcing the admin credentials. Part of our standard rollout package is installing the [All in One WP Security and Firewall](https://wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-wp-security-and-firewall/) plugin. Part of the functionality of this plugin is the ability to rename the login page from wp-admin to just about anything.

Presumably, this takes away the login screen from brute force attackers as they (theoretically) do not know what the new login page is. We continue to see brute force account lockouts even after we've renamed the wp-admin login page.

How is it possible for attackers to continue to attempt to log in if the login page has changed?

Comment: Just because you renamed the login page does not mean it can't be found. Chances are that the renamed page is still 'guessable'. Read more about [security through obscurity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity). A far better approach would be to restrict the admin page by ip (or similar **security**).

Comment: @MatthewPeters This is traffic controlled by bots and I can guarantee that it has not been guessed. The question pertains to how the traffic can get through, and not how I can secure the page (which I can assure you is already done), and as such does not warrant the obligatory "Security through obscurity" speech I see all too often here.

Comment: From your question, I only see the question of `We continue to see brute force account lockouts even after we've renamed the wp-admin login page. How is it possible for attackers to continue to attempt to log in if the login page has changed?` thus I'm only addressing the fact that if all you did was change the login page name, there is no real security added. For instance, even if the page is super obscure, all someone has to do is try to perform an admin task (run a command) that they are not authorised for and it will redirect them to login.

Comment: The redirect might work, or there's software called [dirbuster](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dirbuster/) which brute forces directory structure or simply getting software to spider the directories -  [Burp Spider](http://portswigger.net/burp/spider.html). Matthew is correct about security through obscurity. Restricting the admin page via IP is definitely a better choice.

Comment: There are many ways to redirect /wp-admin/. Many of the methods out there doesn't work as expected. For example, you can still login with /wp-login.php. It is possible that some trace is left that can be used to identify where your login page was moved out, for example in robots.txt.